# Как настроить редирект в этом жутком случае?

Tags: редирект, joomla

Доброго времени суток. Начну с того, что я далеко не программист - более-менее могу что-то делать на joomla. А тут достался сайт, неизвестно кем, как и зачем сделанный... Такого ужаса и нагромождения я еще не встречала... Из админки джумлы он практически не управляется, страницы написаны отдельно в php. Выглядит внутри очень странно. Как будто бы корень сайта скопировали внутрь папки с шаблоном (по сути редактируется все там). И более-менее человеческий вид сайт имеет по адресу:http://ds5.obr-gubkin.ru/templates/ds5/index.php, а не http://ds5.obr-gubkin.ru, как по идее должно быть. Кардинально что-то там перекраивать не хочу - не моя это проблема. Как сделать редирект с http://ds5.obr-gubkin.ru на http://ds5.obr-gubkin.ru/templates/ds5/index.php. Пробовала через .htaccess - не получилось. Может, я что-то не так делаю или задача решается иначе? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Перенесите файлы из папки templates/ds5 в корень сайта, те например было

```
http://ds5.obr-gubkin.ru/templates/ds5/images/header.gif
```

должно стать

```
http://ds5.obr-gubkin.ru/images/header.gif
```

Вы можете самостоятельно посмотреть каких файлов не хватает или где они должны быть - зайдите на сайт по адресу http://ds5.obr-gubkin.ru/, откройте консоль (в гугл хроме ctrl+sift+j) и увидите сообщения об ошибках, где слева само сообщение, справа адрес ошибки.

Например начнем с первой:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

В ответ на попытку загрузить ресурс по адресу

```
   http://ds5.obr-gubkin.ru/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css
```

Получаем ошибку 404, что значит сервер не может найти данные  согласно запросу.

Пробуем зайти по адресу

```
http://ds5.obr-gubkin.ru/templates/ds5/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css
```

Файл открывается. Вам нужно просто переместить папку fancybox в корень сайта, чтобы месторасположение файла соответствовало запросу.

Comment: а можно перенсти файл, и изменить в самом начале исполняемую дерикторию на шаблон )

Comment: Ой, как, оказывается долго и сложно... Боюсь, обрушить его нафиг((((... А водно действие невозможно сделать? Что значит: "а можно перенсти файл, и изменить в самом начале исполняемую дерикторию на шаблон )"? Спасибо.

Comment: @d-mobile я имел в виду, попробовать скопировать индекс из шаблона на основную страницу, и в самом начале скрипта прописать:

    <?php
      chdir('templates/ds5'); // устанавливаем текущую папку для php, возможно путь надо будет абсолютный прописывать.
    ?>

на сколько он будет работать не могу гарантировать.. И во время всех работ делайте резервные копии )

Comment: d-mobile: по сути вам надо выполнить одно действие - скопировать файлы из папки templates/ds5 в корень сайта.

И как сказал IVsevolod не забывайте про резервный копии

Comment: Попробую сегодня. Уточняю, мне надо перенести содержимое папки шаблона в корень или заменить содержимое index в корне на содержимое index из шаблона, добавив в начало 
<?php
  chdir('templates/ds5'); 
?>

Или надо сделать и то, и другое?
Спасибо. Извините, что туплю) Для меня это темный лес)).

По поводу .htacess. Я выложила изначальный, свои редиректы не сработавшие я убрала. Может, добавить туда правильный редирект (какой?) и этим все решить? или невозможно?

Comment: ура!!!! получилось! огромное всем спасибо! Остался еще один вопрос по этому странному сайту. хочу к одному из пунктов меню привязать форму отзывов - типа rs monials. Но ввиду того, что там все не как у людей (в нормальной джумле), не представляю, как это сделать. Меню же из админки не управляется - только кодами.

Answer (score 0):

Хм. Идея следующая: выполнить скрипт из шаблонов на главной странице. Не знаю на сколько это попортит логику сайта ).

```
<?php
  chdir('templates/ds5'); // устанавливаем текущую папку для php, возможно путь надо будет абсолютный прописывать.
  include_once 'index.php'; // запускаем index, по идеи с папки template/ds5 должен обработать
?>
```

---

Покажите ваш .htaccess как вы его написали

Comment: .htaccess, увидев, что ничего не изменилось, вернула к первоначальному виду. Вот он:

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
#<Files ~ "\.xml$">
#Order allow,deny
#Deny from all
#Satisfy all
#</Files>
## End of deny access to extension xml files

Comment: # Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]

Comment: # Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

Comment: RewriteRule ^$ http://ds5.obr-gubkin.ru/templates/ds5/index.php [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

Comment: хм, но у вас в htaccess ничего не было сказано на счет обращение к другому адресу